# Кнопки не видят key из localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, json, localstorage

При нажатии на кнопки готово или удалить дело соответственно, выводит ошибки в консоль

Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement. (todo-app.js:104)

и

Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement. (todo-app.js:114)

как я понимаю, кнопка не может найти key, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста

```js
(function() {
  let session = [];

  // создаём и возвращаем заголовок приложения
  function createAppTitle(title) {
    let appTitle = document.createElement("h2");
    appTitle.innerHTML = title;
    return appTitle;
  }

  // создаём и возвращаем форму для создания дела
  function createTodoItemForm() {
    let form = document.createElement("form");
    let input = document.createElement("input");
    let buttonWrapper = document.createElement("div");
    let button = document.createElement("button");

    form.classList.add("input-group", "mb-3");
    input.classList.add("form-control");
    input.placeholder = "Введите название нового дела";
    buttonWrapper.classList.add("input-group-append");
    button.classList.add("btn", "btn-primary");
    button.textContent = "Добавить дело";
    button.disabled = true;

    buttonWrapper.append(button);
    form.append(input);
    form.append(buttonWrapper);

    input.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (input.value.length > 0) {
        button.disabled = false;
      }
      if (input.value.length == 0) button.disabled = true;
    });

    return {
      form,
      input,
      button,
    };
  }

  // создаём и возвращаем список элементов
  function createTodoList() {
    let list = document.createElement("ul");
    list.classList.add("list-group");
    return list;
  }

  function createTodoItem(name) {
    let item = document.createElement("li");
    // кнопки помещаем в элемент, который красиво покажет их в одной группе
    let buttonGroup = document.createElement("div");
    let doneButton = document.createElement("button");
    let deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

    const id = Math.random() * 15.75;
    item.id = id.toFixed(2);


    item.classList.add(
      "list-group-item",
      "d-flex",
      "justify-content-between",
      "align-items-center"
    );
    item.textContent = name;

    buttonGroup.classList.add("btn-group", "btn-group-sm");
    doneButton.classList.add("btn", "btn-success");
    doneButton.textContent = "Готово";
    deleteButton.classList.add("btn", "btn-danger");
    deleteButton.textContent = "Удалить";


    buttonGroup.append(doneButton);
    buttonGroup.append(deleteButton);
    item.append(buttonGroup);


    return {
      item,
      doneButton,
      deleteButton,
      buttonGroup,
    };
  }

  function changeItemDone(arr, todoItem) {
    arr.map(obj => {
      if (obj.id == todoItem.id & obj.done == false) {
        obj.done = true;
      } else {
        obj.done = false;
      }
    });
  }

  function completeTodoItem(item, btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      session = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
      item.classList.toggle('list-group-item-success');
      changeItemDone(session, item);
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(session));
    });
  }

  function deleteTodoItem(item, btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (confirm('Вы уверены?')) {
        session = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
        const newList = session.filter(obj => obj.id != item.id);
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(newList));
        item.remove();
      }
    });
  };

  function createTodoApp(container, title, todoItemsDefault, key) {
    let todoAppTitle = createAppTitle(title);
    let todoItemForm = createTodoItemForm();
    let todoList = createTodoList();

    container.append(todoAppTitle);
    container.append(todoItemForm.form);
    container.append(todoList);

    if (localStorage.getItem(key)) {
      session = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key))

      for (const obj of session) {
        const todoItem = createTodoItem(todoItemForm.form.value);
        todoItem.item.textContent = obj.name;
        todoItem.item.id = obj.id;
        if (obj.done == true) {
          todoItem.item.classList.add('list-group-item-success');
        } else {
          todoItem.item.classList.remove('list-group-item-success');
        }

        completeTodoItem(todoItem.item, todoItem.doneButton);
        deleteTodoItem(todoItem.item, todoItem.deleteButton);

        todoList.append(todoItem.item);
        todoItem.item.append(todoItem.buttonGroup);
      };
    };

    if (todoItemsDefault) {
      todoItemsDefault.map((item) => {
        let todoItem = createTodoItem(item.name);
        todoList.append(todoItem.item);
        completeTodoItem(todoItem.item, todoItem.doneButton);
        deleteTodoItem(todoItem.item, todoItem.deleteButton);

        todoList.append(todoItem.item);
        todoItem.item.append(todoItem.buttonGroup);
      });
    }


    todoItemForm.input.addEventListener('input', function() {
      todoItemForm.button.disabled = (todoItemForm.input.value == '')
    })

    todoItemForm.form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (!todoItemForm.input.value) {
        return;
      }

      let todoItem = createTodoItem(todoItemForm.input.value);

      completeTodoItem(todoItem.item, todoItem.doneButton);
      deleteTodoItem(todoItem.item, todoItem.deleteButton);

      let locStorData = localStorage.getItem(key);
      if (locStorData == null) {
        session = [];
      } else {
        session = JSON.parse(locStorData);
      }

      const addLocStor = (arr) => {
        const itemObj = {};
        itemObj.name = todoItemForm.input.value;
        itemObj.id = todoItem.item.id;
        itemObj.done = false;

        arr.push(itemObj);
      }
      addLocStor(session);
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(session));

      todoList.append(todoItem.item);

      todoItemForm.input.value = '';
      todoItemForm.button.disabled = true;
    });

  }


  window.createTodoApp = createTodoApp;
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <title>TODO</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script defer src="todo-app.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      createTodoApp(document.getElementById('todo-app'), 'Мои дела', null, 'myKey')
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mb-5">
    <nav class="nav">
      <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Мои дела</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="dad.html">Дела для папы</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="mom.html">Дела для мамы</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="todo-app" class="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Задай константу `key` в начало скрипта. По этому ключу сохраняются задачи в `localStorage`
2. 113 строка выводит `null` если `localStorage` пуст, следовательно ошибка далее. Пометил комментом над исправлением.
   Рабочий код:

```js
(function () {
  let session = [];
  // по этому ключу сохраняются данные в storage
  const key = 'STORAGE';

  // создаём и возвращаем заголовок приложения
  function createAppTitle(title) {
    let appTitle = document.createElement('h2');
    appTitle.innerHTML = title;
    return appTitle;
  }

  // создаём и возвращаем форму для создания дела
  function createTodoItemForm() {
    let form = document.createElement('form');
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    let buttonWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    let button = document.createElement('button');

    form.classList.add('input-group', 'mb-3');
    input.classList.add('form-control');
    input.placeholder = 'Введите название нового дела';
    buttonWrapper.classList.add('input-group-append');
    button.classList.add('btn', 'btn-primary');
    button.textContent = 'Добавить дело';
    button.disabled = true;

    buttonWrapper.append(button);
    form.append(input);
    form.append(buttonWrapper);

    input.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (input.value.length > 0) {
        button.disabled = false;
      }
      if (input.value.length == 0) button.disabled = true;
    });

    return {
      form,
      input,
      button,
    };
  }

  // создаём и возвращаем список элементов
  function createTodoList() {
    let list = document.createElement('ul');
    list.classList.add('list-group');
    return list;
  }

  function createTodoItem(name) {
    let item = document.createElement('li');
    // кнопки помещаем в элемент, который красиво покажет их в одной группе
    let buttonGroup = document.createElement('div');
    let doneButton = document.createElement('button');
    let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

    const id = Math.random() * 15.75;
    item.id = id.toFixed(2);

    item.classList.add(
      'list-group-item',
      'd-flex',
      'justify-content-between',
      'align-items-center'
    );
    item.textContent = name;

    buttonGroup.classList.add('btn-group', 'btn-group-sm');
    doneButton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-success');
    doneButton.textContent = 'Готово';
    deleteButton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-danger');
    deleteButton.textContent = 'Удалить';

    buttonGroup.append(doneButton);
    buttonGroup.append(deleteButton);
    item.append(buttonGroup);

    return {
      item,
      doneButton,
      deleteButton,
      buttonGroup,
    };
  }

  function changeItemDone(arr, todoItem) {
    arr.map((obj) => {
      if ((obj.id == todoItem.id) & (obj.done == false)) {
        obj.done = true;
      } else {
        obj.done = false;
      }
    });
  }

  function completeTodoItem(item, btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
      session = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
      item.classList.toggle('list-group-item-success');
      changeItemDone(session, item);
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(session));
    });
  }

  function deleteTodoItem(item, btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
      if (confirm('Вы уверены?')) {
        // здесь выводит null, если в памяти не сохранены значения или пусто. Соответственно, ошибка
        session = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) || [];
        const newList = session.filter((obj) => obj.id != item.id);
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(newList));
        item.remove();
      }
    });
  }

  function createTodoApp(container, title, todoItemsDefault, key) {
    let todoAppTitle = createAppTitle(title);
    let todoItemForm = createTodoItemForm();
    let todoList = createTodoList();

    container.append(todoAppTitle);
    container.append(todoItemForm.form);
    container.append(todoList);

    if (localStorage.getItem(key)) {
      session = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));

      for (const obj of session) {
        const todoItem = createTodoItem(todoItemForm.form.value);
        todoItem.item.textContent = obj.name;
        todoItem.item.id = obj.id;
        if (obj.done == true) {
          todoItem.item.classList.add('list-group-item-success');
        } else {
          todoItem.item.classList.remove('list-group-item-success');
        }

        completeTodoItem(todoItem.item, todoItem.doneButton);
        deleteTodoItem(todoItem.item, todoItem.deleteButton);

        todoList.append(todoItem.item);
        todoItem.item.append(todoItem.buttonGroup);
      }
    }

    if (todoItemsDefault) {
      todoItemsDefault.map((item) => {
        let todoItem = createTodoItem(item.name);
        todoList.append(todoItem.item);
        completeTodoItem(todoItem.item, todoItem.doneButton);
        deleteTodoItem(todoItem.item, todoItem.deleteButton);

        todoList.append(todoItem.item);
        todoItem.item.append(todoItem.buttonGroup);
      });
    }

    todoItemForm.input.addEventListener('input', function () {
      todoItemForm.button.disabled = todoItemForm.input.value == '';
    });

    todoItemForm.form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (!todoItemForm.input.value) {
        return;
      }

      let todoItem = createTodoItem(todoItemForm.input.value);

      completeTodoItem(todoItem.item, todoItem.doneButton);
      deleteTodoItem(todoItem.item, todoItem.deleteButton);

      let locStorData = localStorage.getItem(key);
      if (locStorData == null) {
        session = [];
      } else {
        session = JSON.parse(locStorData);
      }

      const addLocStor = (arr) => {
        const itemObj = {};
        itemObj.name = todoItemForm.input.value;
        itemObj.id = todoItem.item.id;
        itemObj.done = false;

        arr.push(itemObj);
      };
      addLocStor(session);
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(session));

      todoList.append(todoItem.item);

      todoItemForm.input.value = '';
      todoItemForm.button.disabled = true;
    });
  }

  window.createTodoApp = createTodoApp;
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <title>TODO</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script defer src="todo-app.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        createTodoApp(
          document.getElementById('todo-app'),
          'Мои дела',
          null,
          'myKey'
        );
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container mb-5">
      <nav class="nav">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Мои дела</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="dad.html">Дела для папы</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="mom.html">Дела для мамы</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="todo-app" class="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Здравствуй, теперь он создает массив с ключом STORAGE и кидает туда удаленные элементы,но при перезагрузке страницы вновь их показывает

Comment: Нашел в чем проблема была, я просто функции с кнопками засунул в функцию createTodoApp. все заработало, у меня же key там параметром задается, теперь почти все работает корректно, вот только сделанные дела когда помечаешь, оставляет в хранилище только последнее отмеченное